# Programmatically post an image on a comment at Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I used the Facebook API to post an image or a comment on the wall using an iPhone. But I am trying to post an image on someone's comment through my application. How can we programmatically post an image to someone's post as a comment?

Comment: did you mean you want to post an image in comment box ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *[Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)* you can post comments to an object's /comments connection, but the only argument it takes is "message". So, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you paste a URL to an image in a post, it automatically appears as an image, but I don't think I've ever seen images in comments on posts.

You can try putting it inside `<img src="pic-url-goes-here">`, but I'm pretty sure that does not work in replies at least.

If it really is impossible, you should (ask to) modify your application's functionality. Uploading the image from the application and linking to it in the comment would at least "get it in there" (as a link).